# Simple communication via MQTT between node apps

Tags: node.js, mqtt

Hi I'm really new to MQTT and I've read a lot of posts and blogs about it the last days, yet I seem not to fully understand the different parts needed, such as Broker, Clients.

I want two node apps to communicate with each other via a local mqtt service. As far as I understand, this mqtt service is called broker. I managed it to let 2 node apps communicate via a public broker like this:

**app1 (sender)**

```
 const mqtt = require('mqtt');

 // to be changed to own local server/service
 const client = mqtt.connect('http://broker.hivemq.com');

 client.on('connect', () => {
     let id = 0;
     setInterval(() => {
         client.publish('myTopic', 'my message - ' + ++id);
     }, 3000);
 });
```

**app2 (receiver)**

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');

// to be changed to own local server/service
const client = mqtt.connect('http://broker.hivemq.com');

client.on('connect', () => {
    client.subscribe('myTopic');
});

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    console.log('MSG: %s: %s', topic, message);
});
```

As this worked, I wanted to move on by replacing the **public broker** with a **private** one. After a while I found **[mqtt-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt-server)** as a node package.

So I tried the following as a third node app, which is supposed to be the broker for **app1** and **app2**:

**server (MQTT broker)**

```
fs = require('fs');
mqttServer = require('mqtt-server');
let subscriptions = [];

let servers = mqttServer(
  // servers to start
  {
    mqtt: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:1883',
    mqttws: 'ws://127.0.0.1:1884',
  },
  // options
  {
    emitEvents: true
  },
  // client handler
  function (client) {
    client.connack({
      returnCode: 0
});

client.on('publish', (msg) => {
  let topic = msg.topic;
  let content = msg.payload.toString();
    // this works, it outputs the topic and the message.
    // problem is: app2 does not receive them.
    // do we have to forward them somehow here?
    console.log(topic, content);

    });

    client.on('subscribe', (sub) => {
      let newSubscription = sub.subscriptions[0];
      subscriptions.push(newSubscription);
      console.log('New subscriber to topic:', newSubscription.topic);
    });
  });

servers.listen(function () {
  console.log('MQTT servers now listening.');
});
```

### Problem

After adjusting the connection-Uris (both to `ws://127.0.0.1:1884`) in **app1** and **app2** The server app **receives all messages that are published** and **recognises that someone connected and listens to a specific topic**.

**But:** While the server gets all those events/messages, **app2 does not receive those messages anymore**. Deducing that, something with this broker must be wrong, since using the public broker everything works just fine.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update the question to show the exactly what you've changed the client connect urls to.

Comment: Thank you for the advice :) Updated it.

Comment: First suggestion, try a different broker, something like Mosca if you want to keep it nodejs based or mosquitto

Comment: I tried mosca but I didn't get it work as well, since it needs Redis (or other db) and I do not understand how to get this running / why this is needed anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't get `mqtt-server` to work either, so try Mosca.

Mosca only needs a back end if you want to send QOS1/2 messages, it will work with out one.

```
var mosca = require('mosca');

var settings = {
    port:1883
}

var server = new mosca.Server(settings);

server.on('ready', function(){
  console.log("ready");
});
```

That will start a mqtt broker on port 1883

You need to make sure your clients are connecting with raw mqtt not websockets, so makes sure the urls start `mqtt://`